# Utilizing RSpec w/ Capybara on Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my app/controllers/pet_controller.rb file I have some code

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :process_params, only: [:create, :edit]
  # GET /pets
  # GET /pets.json
  def index
    @pets = Pet.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM pets WHERE \"userId\" = ?", params[:userId].to_i]
  end
.
.
.
```

I have some code in my spec/pets_spec.rb that looks like

```
describe PetsController do
    describe 'GET #index' do
        it { is_expected.to respond_with :ok }
    end
end
```

To have a simple test if the controller responds correctly. 
When I invoke *bundle exec rspec*, I get a

```
/spec/pets_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant PetsController (NameError)
```

I am very new to using this testing tool, any help to get this started would be greatly appreciated.

-Otterman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't install `rspec` all the way for Rails.

[Read this introduction](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/gettingstarted).

That will generate two files: `spec/spec_helper.rb` and `spec/rails_helper.rb`. Open those up and read the comments of how they work and what they are for.

Then run `bundle exec rake spec` or `bundle exec rspec spec`.